# Algorithm for determining equality of First-Order logic terms

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, first-order-logic, unification

Can anyone guide me on how to implement an algorithm that can determine the equality of first-order logic terms. Here what's it look like.

- The terms consist only **constant** and **function** symbols. For example, $f(a, h(b, c))$.
- The premise can contain equality of any kinds of terms. For example, $\{f(a) = b, g(h) = x\}$

The algorithm would take 2 terms and list of equality premises and then derive a conclusion whether or not the terms are equal.

```
fn equals(first: Term, second: Term, equalities: List<(Term, Term)>) -> bool { ... }
```

For example, consider the term $f(a, b)$, $f(x, y)$, and equality premises of $\{x=a,y=b\}$, with these conditions, the term $f(a, b)$ should be equal with $f(x, y)$.

Currently, I only know about First-Order logic, Natural Deduction, and Unification. Is there an algorithm for this problem or which topics should I studied more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such algorithm. In particular, the problem of determining whether two elements of a [finitely presented group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) are equal is undecidable. For documentation of that fact, see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) on the problem.

Comment: So this problem is **partially-undecidable** right? This means that there's an algorithm that can output *true* in the equal cases but might either output *false* or never halt in the non-equal cases.

Comment: This is correct. Proofs are recursively enunerable, so one can go through all possible proofs until finding a proof the two items are equal, then halt.